# extract entries from a given hash map and transfer them to another hash map

Tags: rust

How to extract entries from a `HashMap` and transfer them to another `HashMap` in Rust. In C++ I could in the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

void print(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& data) {
    for (const auto&[key, val] : data) {
        std::cout << key << ": " << val << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::unordered_map<std::string, int> extract(std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& mapp) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mappp;

    for (auto itr = mapp.begin(); itr != mapp.end(); ) {
        if (itr->second > 200) {
            auto prev_itr = itr++;
            mappp.insert(mapp.extract(prev_itr));
        } else {
            ++itr;
        }
    }

    return mappp;
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mapp {
        {"abc", 123},
        {"def", 67},
        {"ghi", 380},
        {"jkl", 4376}
    };

    print(mapp);

    auto mappp = extract(mapp);
    print(mapp);
    print(mappp);
}
```

Rust Equivalent(`extract` function is incomplete)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn print(mapp: &HashMap<String, i32>) {
    for (key, val) in mapp {
        println!("{}: {}", key, val);
    }
    println!("");
}

fn extract(mapp: &mut HashMap<String, i32>) -> HashMap<String, i32> {
    // mapp.iter().filter(&|(_, val)| val > 200)
    HashMap::new()
}

fn main() {
    let mut mapp: HashMap<String, i32> = HashMap::new();
    
    mapp.insert("abc".to_string(), 123);
    mapp.insert("def".to_string(), 67);
    mapp.insert("ghi".to_string(), 380);
    mapp.insert("jkl".to_string(), 4376);
    
    print(&mapp);
    
    let mappp = extract(&mut mapp);
    
    print(&mapp);
    print(&mappp);
}
```

Comment: I believe you need `HashMap::drain_filter` but it's not stable yet: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.drain_filter.

Comment: @Dogbert I cannot use unstable api's as of now. Is there an alternative way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

As `drain_filter` is not stable yet, one less ideal option (because more allocations and more traffic) would be to `drain` the original map distributing its contents into *two* targets, then set the old map to one of the targets

```rust
fn extract(mapp: &mut HashMap<String, i32>) -> HashMap<String, i32> {
    let mut old = HashMap::new();
    let mut new = HashMap::new();
    for (k, v) in mapp.drain() {
        if v > 200 {
            new.insert(k, v);
        } else {
            old.insert(k, v);
        }
    }
    *mapp = old;
    new
}
```

A possibly slightly more efficient alternative would be to collect the old entries into a `Vec` then `extend()` the old map:

```rust
fn extract(mapp: &mut HashMap<String, i32>) -> HashMap<String, i32> {
    let mut old = Vec::new();
    let mut new = HashMap::new();
    for (k, v) in mapp.drain() {
        if v > 200 {
            new.insert(k, v);
        } else {
            old.push((k, v));
        }
    }
    mapp.extend(old);
    new
}
```

It still needs to rehash and redistribute the re-inserted entries, but for large-ish datasizes it should have a lower memory high water mark, as vecs require less space than maps. It would also avoid discarding the allocation associated with `mapp` which depending on the way it's usd thereafter could be useful.

Yet an older alternative would be to depend on [`hashbrown`](https://github.com/rust-lang/hashbrown) directly, that's the actual underlying implementation of the standard map, and [it added `drain_filter` back in late 2019](https://github.com/rust-lang/hashbrown/pull/135).

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this efficiently, you need [`extract_if`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.extract_if)*, which is currently nightly.

```rs
#![feature(hash_extract_if)]
use std::hash::Hash;

fn extract<K, V, F>(mapp: &mut HashMap<K, V>, condition: F) -> HashMap<K, V>
where
    F: FnMut(&K, &mut V) -> bool,
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    mapp.extract_if(condition).collect()
}
```

I've made this generic so it can be compared to the other methods.

If you want to use this on stable rust, you can use the [hashbrown](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/) crate, which is what the standard library currently uses internally. Nearly the entire API from std is in hashbrown verbatim, plus some things like [`extract_if`](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.extract_if).

An almost perfect way to do this in stable rust is to use `retain`. This requires cloning the keys and replacing the values, which for most hash maps would be fast, but having `String` keys makes this not ideal.

```rs
fn extract<K, V, F>(mapp: &mut HashMap<K, V>, mut condition: F) -> HashMap<K, V>
where
    F: FnMut(&K, &mut V) -> bool,
    K: Eq + Hash + Clone,
    V: Default,
{
    let mut new_map = HashMap::new();
    mapp.retain(|k, v| {
        if condition(k, v) {
            let k = k.clone();
            let v = std::mem::take(v);
            new_map.insert(k, v);
            false
        } else {
            true
        }
    });
    new_map
}
```

If the values don't implement `Default`, you can use a placeholder value.

The other answer(s) are good for truly generic keys and values.

Here's one using `partition`.

```rs
fn extract<K, V, F>(mapp: &mut HashMap<K, V>, mut condition: F) -> HashMap<K, V>
where
    F: FnMut(&K, &V) -> bool,
    K: Eq + Hash,
{
    let (new, old) = std::mem::take(mapp)
        .into_iter()
        .partition(|(k, v)| condition(k, v));
    *mapp = old;
    new
}
```

The downside to these is that it discards the original allocation and makes two new ones, whereas the other methods reuse the original allocation.

---

* `extract_if` was recently renamed, so it's only visible online in the nightly std library at the moment. Right now, stable std (which shows nightly features from when the last stable released) calls it [`drain_filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.drain_filter).